# Interface name with a dot as in packages

Tags: java, android

I have a class which implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener. What does a dot mean here? Is it a package? If NavigationView is the name of interface then what is OnNavigationItemSelectedListener? Is it a class or an interface within an interface?

Comment: NavigationView is Class not interface and OnNavigationItemSelectedListener is interface - Listener for handling events on navigation items, And dot is operator access the interface inside class

Comment: This is nested class (in this case `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` is interface)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NavigationView is a class whereas OnNavigationItemSelectedListener is the name of the interface present in NavigationView class.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interface

[From docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) it's clearly seen the type and look here also for specification [NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener.html)

Why we need it? Read [Creating event callbacks to the activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks)